# Probability of a vertex not belonging to a set of edges in a random hypergraph.

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs, probabilistic-method, hypergraphs

Let $H(n,p)$ be a $r$-uniform random hypergraph on $n$ vertices, with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$. Let $E' \subset E$ be a set of edges with some known characteristics, and $V' = V \setminus \{u_i: u_i \text{ is a vertex of } e, e \in E'\}$.

I have several questions about this:

1. My note says that $$|V'| = \sum_{v \in V} 1_{\{v \in V'\}}, \text{ and } \mathbb{E}\left[ 1_{\{v \in V'\}} \right] = \mathbb{P}(v \in V') = (1 - p)^{\text{deg}(v)}.$$
   But if we know deg$(v)$, shouldn't we already know the exact value of $1_{\{v \in V'\}}$, and hence do not need to estimate it by its expected value?
2. Say we accept this line of reasoning, wouldn't a more appropriate statmement be
   $$\mathbb{P}(v \in V') \leq (1 - p)^{\text{deg}(v)},$$
   with equality achieved if all edges adjacent to $v$ are in $E'$?
3. Regardless of the above, why can't I get $\mathbb{P}(v \in V')$ in the following way?
   \begin{align} & \mathbb{P}(v \in \{u_i: u_i \text{ is a vertex of } e, e \in E'\}) = p^{\text{deg}(v)} \\  
   \Rightarrow & \ \mathbb{P}(v \in V') = \mathbb{P}(v \notin \{u_i: u_i \text{ is a vertex of } e, e \in E'\}) = 1 - p^{\text{deg}(v)}.\end{align}

**Edit:** Please have a look at [slides](http://discretemath.imp.fu-berlin.de/DMIII-2020/slides/Chapter6.pdf) 33 and 37 for the context of the question, if necessary.

Comment: Your concern in point 1 is valid.  In general it is not possible to conclude such probabilities.  In fact $P[v \in V']$ cannot be computed without more information about what is meant by $E'$ and $V'$ having "some known characteristics." Those "known characteristics" might depend on the realization of the graph itself, which would then influence the probabilities.

Comment: I also observe that the expression $V \setminus (\cup_{e \in E'} e)$ does not make sense because $V$ is a set of vertices while  $(\cup_{e \in E'} e)$ is a set of edges. It is not possible to "disregard the abuse of notation here."

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've just edited the question and added a few more details.

Comment: I've bookmarked that book chapter out of fondness for combinatorics and probabilistic methods.  However the context is everything in your problem.  When you write "if we know deg$(v)$", how do you mean this?  Is it with regard to hyperedges $E$ or $E'$?  While these are said to be $r$-uniform, this tells us nothing about the degree of any particular vertex $v$.

Comment: This is also something I'm not sure about. I understand deg$(v)$ here is w.r.t. $E$. Regardless, since $H$ is a random graph, I think we can at most putting bounds on deg$(v)$, based on some characteristics of $H$, but not getting a definite value like the proof seems to be saying.

Comment: Question 3 looks like a separate issue so I'd like to get an opinion on it first if possible.

Comment: If $v$ is a given vertex and $deg(v)$ is the random degree (with respect to the randomly chosen edges $E$) then for any event $A$ the equation $P[A] = p^{deg(v)}$ does not make sense because the left-hand-side is a number and the right-hand-side is a random variable.  However if we assume $E$ is a fixed (nonrandom) graph and $deg(v)$ is the (nonrandom) degree of vertex $v$ with respect to $E$, and if edges in $E'$ are chosen independently and randomly with prob $p$ over all edges in $E$, then $P[v \in V']= (1-p)^{deg(v)}$ makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've just realized one of my misunderstanding is that I was thinking of $p$ as the edge-probability of $H$ why in fact $H$ is not random.